# populateDocumentTemplate with nested object

Tags: web, pspdfkit

As mentioned in the documentation https://pspdfkit.com/api/web/PSPDFKit.html#.populateDocumentTemplate we can populate placeholders with keys of a given object exmaple if we pass {"name": "test"}  in model key we can load any {{name}} as test in an docx file(with {{ }} being the start&end of the delimiter).

can we do the same for nested object like { "name": { "firstname": "test", "lastname": "test" } } and put {{name.firstname}} as a placeholder?